# discord.gateway: Shard ID None has successfully RESUMED session

Tags: python, discord.py

I am a student studying discord programming. While executing the function in the while loop, no error occurred, but "discord.gateway: Shard ID None has successfully RESUMED session " is displayed, and the loop execution stops. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Can you provide an example of code which failed please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: why do you use `loop`? What code do you run?